# How to throttle bandwidth speed from VPS

Tags: ubuntu, bandwidth, network-speed

I was wondering if you can throttle/boost the download speed from my VPS to me, because now and often I download a database which is quite big, typically 5-7GB. My side is quite slow (typically I have max speeds of 100Kb/s) so I was wondering if it's possible to throttle the bandwidth speed from my server to me that it could make the download much faster.

If this is possible, how can I do this?

My server is running Ubuntu 11.04 with a 100Mbps line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throttling the bandwidth will reduce it and make things slower, not faster.  If your connection is 100Kb/sec, there's nothing that will increase your actual transfer speed above that.

Your best bet, if you aren't doing this right now, is to compress the DB before transferring it.  gzip, 7zip, bzip2, and numerous other tools can all be used to reduce the size of the file, which will reduce the time it takes to transfer.  In my experience, Databases usually compress pretty well, on the order of 50% to 90%+ compression ratio.